# Backbone JS: Rendering template without something like $('body').append?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using an external template, I am trying to render a Backbone JS view to the DOM. Unfortunately, I only get a blank screen, while checking with the console confirms that everything is working.

To get the rendered template in the DOM, I have to do something like `$('body').append(myView.render().el);`, which according to many resources shouldn't be necessary. For example, [this view](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/js/views/todo-view.js#L39-L56) from the TodoMVC project's Backbone implementation  does not incorporate anything like `$('body').append`, which makes me believe something in my code is wrong, but I can't find it.

The template in my HTML looks like this:

```
<script id="name-template" type="text/template">
    <%= name %> (<%=age %>)
</script>
```

And this is the application code:

```
var App = App || {};

App.Models = {};
App.Views = {};

App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 34
    }
});

App.Views.Person = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',
    template: _.template($('#name-template').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this.model);
    }
});

App.personModel = new App.Models.Person();
App.personView = new App.Views.Person({model: personModel});
App.personView.render();
```

What do I have to change so that upon page load, the rendered template is added the DOM?

Comment: in the todoMVC example the view element is already on the page

Comment: But look at [#35 of Appview](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/js/views/app-view.js#L35) and [#80](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/js/views/app-view.js#L80) The div into with the view has to be rendered is hardcoded. In the same way your application can have a div into which the view will be rendered, otherwise $('body') is the only way

Comment: You can set the `el` to point to an existing DOM element, and if you do that, there's no need to append it again. I am on the camp that believe that linking the existing DOM with your backbone app is a bad practice that creates unnecessary tight coupling.

Comment: @UziKilon That's my opinion too, that's why I actually tried to avoid a "manual append". But is it right then that there is no way around it when using templates? (That means, one needs to focus more on how the templates are put together)

Comment: @Sven Using a template really doesn't change any of this, it's just an easier/cleaner way of generating the html you want. I think you are possibly misunderstanding what the `el` is, I've tried to clarify this a bit in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short anwser is that the `el` can point to a element that is already part of the DOM and if you do that you don't need to manually append it. To do this you can simple pass in the reference when you create your view instance, for example

```
App.personView = new App.Views.Person({model: personModel, el: '#someElement'});
App.personView.render();
```

Here's the slightly longer version.

A backbone `el` is really just a reference to a DOM element whether it's already been attached to the page or not and it really isn't any different in this sense then a regular reference to a DOM element. Consider the following plain vanilla JavaScript code

```
var pElement = document.createElement("p");
var pElement = $('p'); //using jQuery
```

At this point *pElement* contains a reference to a DOM element but isn't attached to the page (yet). Anything you attach to this `p` element won't be visibly until you attach it to the page using something like the following

```
document.body.appendChild(pElement);
$('body').append(pElement); //or using jQuery
```

If instead of creating a new `p` element you instead got a reference to an existing element, any changes you made to that element would immediately be reflected on the page,

```
var pElement = document.getElementById('#myPElement');
var pElement = $('#myPElement'); //using jquery
```

At this point you can manipulate the *pElement* as you wish without attaching it to the page since it already is part of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Indeed, I was thinking that `el` was part of some magic Backbone performs. I didn't expect it to be just a simple reference.